# Amazon Aurora Alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a Amazon aurora cluster, with a writer and reader.
I have Alarms created on top of both writer and reader with different threshold.
As we know that AWS reserves the right to exchange reader & writer roles at maintenance windows.
Now I have an issue, when I get alarms, its like I got alarm for reader but actually now that reader has become the write and my threshold in CF template was accordingly, How can I overcome this scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Amazon Aurora monitoring documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html), you should do the following:

> For Aurora, use WRITER or READER role metrics to set up alarms instead of relying on metrics for specific DB instances. Aurora DB instance roles can change roles over time. You can find these role-based metrics in the CloudWatch console.

Also, check this [page](https://lukewaite.ca/posts/2017/08/21/aws-aurora-monitoring.html) where it shows the role metrics.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, Yes I saw that but I want to achieve it from cloud formation. in that I am not where to mention the Role field ?

Comment: @WaseemMir It is a `Dimension` on the metric, so see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudwatch-alarm-metric.html how you can specify and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-dimension.html for an example.